# Reference local .csv file in altair chart

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega-lite

I'm trying to use [altair](https://altair-viz.github.io/) to visualize data, but I struggle to use it in the way I would like to use it: by not embedding the data inside the generated `.html` chart, but by referencing the local `.csv` file that contains the data. Otherwise, it would result in duplicating the data and therefore doubling the required storage.

Here's what I tried:

```py
import os
import altair as alt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# Dummy data.

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "x": np.arange(n),
    "y": np.random.randn(n),
})

# Using the dataframe directly.

chartdf = alt.Chart(df).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
)
chartdf.save('chartdf.html') 

# Now referencing the local .csv file.

filename = "data.csv"
df.to_csv(filename)
directory = os.getcwd()
fullpath = "file://" + os.path.join(directory, filename)

alt.data_transformers.enable('csv')
chartcsv = alt.Chart(fullpath).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y='y:Q',
)
chartcsv.save('chartcsv.html')
```

As a result, I get two `.html`files. Here's `chartdf.html`, correctly showing the plot, but storing the data in the source code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    (function(vegaEmbed) {
      var spec = {"config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300}}, "data": {"name": "data-1727235c61a7b22ee660b7640869d48d"}, "mark": "line", "encoding": {"x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"}, "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "y"}}, "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json", "datasets": {"data-1727235c61a7b22ee660b7640869d48d": [{"x": 0, "y": 0.2112352635569061}, {"x": 1, "y": -0.6297931563725685}, {"x": 2, "y": -1.6669551411704615}, {"x": 3, "y": -0.8590377939062339}, {"x": 4, "y": -2.362675608121853}, {"x": 5, "y": 0.1816769959879393}, {"x": 6, "y": 0.21964717520484453}, {"x": 7, "y": 0.5924276442771413}, {"x": 8, "y": 2.062942588202062}, {"x": 9, "y": -1.411207827356746}, {"x": 10, "y": -2.2266024022172957}, {"x": 11, "y": 0.47229354076715996}, {"x": 12, "y": -0.14474440245785294}, {"x": 13, "y": 0.051738284319541146}, {"x": 14, "y": -0.4838552098939953}, {"x": 15, "y": 0.29366971719427554}, {"x": 16, "y": 0.18361573516404703}, {"x": 17, "y": 0.6734430961408209}, {"x": 18, "y": -1.6084727160210788}, {"x": 19, "y": 0.457742541113758}, {"x": 20, "y": -1.4873380353155474}, {"x": 21, "y": 0.6118088150042575}, {"x": 22, "y": 0.9889323424386781}, {"x": 23, "y": -0.4539168151678354}, {"x": 24, "y": 0.5438198860906843}, {"x": 25, "y": 0.47011997666216776}, {"x": 26, "y": -0.7562418295269627}, {"x": 27, "y": -0.27690138025681765}, {"x": 28, "y": 0.49827375786911876}, {"x": 29, "y": 1.0153141593800437}, {"x": 30, "y": 1.1782385627274985}, {"x": 31, "y": 0.0424730271073153}, {"x": 32, "y": -1.4185058816513483}, {"x": 33, "y": -1.8114268346098452}, {"x": 34, "y": -1.29594887684236}, {"x": 35, "y": 0.09894597002376446}, {"x": 36, "y": -1.4631390515148475}, {"x": 37, "y": -2.1926825852861485}, {"x": 38, "y": 1.1519292846453788}, {"x": 39, "y": -0.5818573231859363}, {"x": 40, "y": -0.02064804413385189}, {"x": 41, "y": 0.5006162765747295}, {"x": 42, "y": -0.9784096515241409}, {"x": 43, "y": 1.7117580547861466}, {"x": 44, "y": 0.8677907294763252}, {"x": 45, "y": -1.3285577876719292}, {"x": 46, "y": 0.385574566953019}, {"x": 47, "y": 1.0251802025168757}, {"x": 48, "y": 0.2255080418305147}, {"x": 49, "y": 0.8012860491915356}, {"x": 50, "y": -1.3742866681331305}, {"x": 51, "y": -0.5160585231146249}, {"x": 52, "y": 1.0086907194824801}, {"x": 53, "y": 1.8441072855180702}, {"x": 54, "y": 0.10647348146379314}, {"x": 55, "y": -0.9950070073653883}, {"x": 56, "y": -0.1209797393395647}, {"x": 57, "y": 1.2957688874221422}, {"x": 58, "y": 1.5377004050922511}, {"x": 59, "y": 0.14393885533903575}, {"x": 60, "y": -1.440499604914547}, {"x": 61, "y": 1.4762530684041733}, {"x": 62, "y": 0.3962335303842206}, {"x": 63, "y": 0.15195105628021952}, {"x": 64, "y": 1.274568257852339}, {"x": 65, "y": -1.9517895004128185}, {"x": 66, "y": -1.6847841535930692}, {"x": 67, "y": 1.3936389293839209}, {"x": 68, "y": -0.11370298418438128}, {"x": 69, "y": 1.8052343535396553}, {"x": 70, "y": -0.3443348662400949}, {"x": 71, "y": 0.8838398407281737}, {"x": 72, "y": 0.8666912228874258}, {"x": 73, "y": 2.33181288689919}, {"x": 74, "y": -1.7370617166021098}, {"x": 75, "y": -0.8447406898036955}, {"x": 76, "y": -0.27812566279331796}, {"x": 77, "y": 0.6939513790408266}, {"x": 78, "y": 1.2769804660273463}, {"x": 79, "y": 1.275176541502504}, {"x": 80, "y": -0.3843801173353608}, {"x": 81, "y": -0.14199480129344477}, {"x": 82, "y": -0.7443885322363791}, {"x": 83, "y": 0.392135684892227}, {"x": 84, "y": -1.4963957824987753}, {"x": 85, "y": -0.05395082651327829}, {"x": 86, "y": -1.1640386653528847}, {"x": 87, "y": -0.8740477495639896}, {"x": 88, "y": 2.367892815244499}, {"x": 89, "y": -1.1861757645950304}, {"x": 90, "y": 0.4862085488887814}, {"x": 91, "y": -1.907728993442288}, {"x": 92, "y": 0.6304124541928168}, {"x": 93, "y": 1.0704432779754836}, {"x": 94, "y": -0.805919444706216}, {"x": 95, "y": 0.829176968267078}, {"x": 96, "y": 0.16050957366472954}, {"x": 97, "y": 1.1663653159345964}, {"x": 98, "y": 0.33908181024409456}, {"x": 99, "y": -0.04008707863910976}]}};
      var embedOpt = {"mode": "vega-lite"};

      function showError(el, error){
          el.innerHTML = ('<div class="error" style="color:red;">'
                          + '<p>JavaScript Error: ' + error.message + '</p>'
                          + "<p>This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. "
                          + "See the javascript console for the full traceback.</p>"
                          + '</div>');
          throw error;
      }
      const el = document.getElementById('vis');
      vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, embedOpt)
        .catch(error => showError(el, error));
    })(vegaEmbed);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the `chartcsv.html` file, not displaying the chart.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .error {
        color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega@5"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-lite@4.8.1"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm//vega-embed@6"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="vis"></div>
  <script>
    (function(vegaEmbed) {
      var spec = {"config": {"view": {"continuousWidth": 400, "continuousHeight": 300}}, "data": {"url": "file:///Users/MY_USER_NAME_WAS_HERE/Projects/ds-python/utilities/plotlibrary/data.csv"}, "mark": "line", "encoding": {"x": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "x"}, "y": {"type": "quantitative", "field": "y"}}, "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.8.1.json"};
      var embedOpt = {"mode": "vega-lite"};

      function showError(el, error){
          el.innerHTML = ('<div class="error" style="color:red;">'
                          + '<p>JavaScript Error: ' + error.message + '</p>'
                          + "<p>This usually means there's a typo in your chart specification. "
                          + "See the javascript console for the full traceback.</p>"
                          + '</div>');
          throw error;
      }
      const el = document.getElementById('vis');
      vegaEmbed("#vis", spec, embedOpt)
        .catch(error => showError(el, error));
    })(vegaEmbed);

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What's the correct way to implement altair charts that use data stored in a local file?

Comment: For using local data files in Jupyterab, you can use `'files/filename.csv'`, but I am not sure how to reference local data in a saved html file. The vega-lite docs suggest to use the relative path as you have done already https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html#url (you would need to change the format to 'csv', but when I tried that on my end it stil didnt' show so waiting for someone else to clarify what's going on)

Comment: can we have a look at your data.csv ? what is the delimiter ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use a local data file in an Altair chart, two conditions need to be met:

1. The file must be specified as a URL valid for the frontend (i.e. browser) displaying the chart
2. The URL must satisfy the security requirements of the browser (e.g. must satisfy cross-origin policies)

Unfortunately, the approach to ensuring (1) and (2) are met is highly dependent on what frontend you're using (i.e. JupyterLab vs. Jupyter Notebook vs. Colab vs. Streamlit vs. ...) and within each of these can even depend on what version of the notebook/server you're running, what browser you're using, what browser security settings you have enabled, whether you're using `http` or `https`, whether or not you use an ad-blocker, what operating system you're using, the precise details of how you launched your notebook server or opened your HTML file, and probably many other variables.

For this reason, as the primary author of Altair, I generally discourage people from attempting to use local data files, because it's quite difficult to answer seemingly simple questions like "how do I reference a local CSV file in an Altair chart?".

If you want to press forward, I would suggest opening your browser's javascript console, where you'll see warnings or errors that could help in diagnosing how you can change things to meet requirements (1) and (2) above within your own setup. If you want something that will just work, I would suggest using pandas to load the file into a dataframe, and create the chart that way.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate answer. This definitely helps and I will make sure to try a different approach. Thank you for your time and the great work with Altair.

Answer (score 0):

## CORS issue

You can not load data from `file://` as it creates Cross-Origin error in Firefox: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at file:///data/data.csv. (Reason: CORS request not http)`.

The easiest is to start de dummy http server in the same directory as the HTML file generates `python -m http.server`

## delimiter issue

By default, a `csv` is supposed to be delimited by comma (`,`), a `tsv` by tabs and a `dsv` by any character that must be specified.

I manage to instruct altair to do it with : `altair.Chart({"url":'data/data.csv',"format":{'type':"dsv"}})`

The python dict passed to `altair.Chart` method mimics the json object that must be passed to [vega](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/data.html#dsv).