# Python Altair Load from JSON

Tags: python, json, altair

looking for help on how to load an altair chart from a json file (contains `dict_keys(['$schema', 'config', 'datasets', 'title', 'vconcat'])`).

The json file was created using the `altair.Chart` method `to_json()` such as below:

```
import altair as alt


chart = alt.Chart(df).mark_line(...).encode(...).properties(...).transform_filter(...)
chart_json = chart.to_json()
```

Here is a sample of the code I would like to run

```
chart = alt.load_json(chart_json)  # made-up, needs replacement
chart.save('chart.png')
```

Disclaimer: I've never used altair and am trying to reverse-engineer a project. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're looking for the `alt.Chart.from_json` method:

```py
new_chart = alt.Chart.from_json(chart_json)
new_chart.display()
```

The method assumes that `chart_json` is a string of JSON representing a valid Altair chart.

Answer (score 0):

Altair can work directly with [json files by specifying their path/url as shown in the documentation](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/data.html):

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data


url = data.cars.url  # URL/path to json data

alt.Chart(url).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower:Q',
    y='Miles_per_Gallon:Q'
)
```

To load a local file, there are several potential issues, including the browser having access to local files and using the correct format for the frontend you're using (e.g. jupyterlab). These have been elaborated on elsewhere:

- [Reference local .csv file in altair chart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67391359/reference-local-csv-file-in-altair-chart)
- https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2529#issuecomment-982643293
- https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/2432